# op amp rails and its inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, ground

[image: Pulse Induction Metal DETECTOR]

I am trying to feed this voltage measured by the oscilloscope to a voltage comparator.
By design the voltage should swing between +0.7 and -0.7. BUT since the voltage is not referenced to ground I am really having a hard time wrapping my head around what should be connected the comparator, and HOW should I connect them.

Since the voltage am trying to feed to the comparator is not referenced to ground, I can't just get away with connecting the op-amp negative rail to ground right?

Just bear with me one more moment, what I am trying to say is if for instance I feed a signal that has a magnitude of 0.7 does that mean it's 0.7 higher in voltage than the op amp ground, or is it independent of the op-amp ground?
I mean if for instance I connected the comparator negative rail to 0.7V and then feed a 0.7 to any of the inputs would I be effectively feeding the op-amp 0 volts since they are both at the same level.
So I guess what am trying to ask is, what are the relation between the + and - rails of the op-amp to it's inputs. what should I connect the - and + rails of the comparator.
I am really confused about what a ground represent in this case.

Comment: The question talks about op amps, but there isn't a single op amp in the schematic. Show us the full circuit.

Comment: The inputs must be < than the V+ and > than the V-. For rail to rail amps the rail voltages are included in the acceptable range. There are some op amps that go slightly beyond rails for inputs, but most don't.

Comment: i am trying to build this circuit i want to feed the voltage measured by the oscilloscope to an op amp working as a comparator, but i haven't yet figured out how it should be connected and that's why it's not in the schematic

Answer (score 1):

The voltages will likely go beyond +/-0.7v in practice. The [1N4007G](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/68708.pdf) datasheet specifies *Vf* or the *maximum forward diode voltage* at about 1.0v when 1A is passing through it. It can take more current than this, up to 30A, for a very brief period of time however. If L1 is a high-power device, more than 1A could flow through either diode briefly, pushing the measured voltage higher than 1V, likely up to +/-3v. Test it and record the output using an oscilloscope for real-world values in your circuit.

Note that the 1N400x series are *relatively slow* and are optimized for rectification purposes. The collapsing magnetic field in L1 when the key is released, will ramp up voltage very quickly. A faster diode may be needed to prevent large voltage spikes from forming. Again, test it and see.

Anyways, a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) outputs it's *positive rail voltage* when it's `positive input` is **greater** than it's `negative input.` It outputs its *negative rail voltage* when the `positive input` is **less than** it's `negative input.`

In general, you can't drive an op-amp's inputs beyond it's supply rails. So it is not possible to power the comparator from 5v and 0v, then apply -3v to an input. How this is mitigated is by the use of [resistor dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider_2) to "scale" and align input signals to values falling within the acceptable range of the comparator. Same with it's output.